# Why is the BLE device not starting on my Arduino Pro Mini?

Tags: c++, arduino-pro-mini

I recently purchased a 5V arduino pro mini that I now wish to connect to a BLE device.

I firstly tried the BLE device with my Uno board and it worked very well! However when I now try to use it on my mini it does not start.

This is my wiring:
First I connect the pro mini to the uno in order to upload the code looking like this:

1. Arduino Mini Pro to Arduino Uno
2. RX --> TX
3. TX --> RX
4. VCC --> 5v
5. GND --> GND
6. RST --> RST

Then I wire the mini to my BLE device (https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/hooking-everything-up):

1. Arduino Mini Pro to BLE nRF8001
2. 13 --> SCK
3. 12 --> MISO
4. 11 --> MOSI
5. 10 --> REQ
6. 9 --> RST
7. 2 --> RDY
8. GND --> GND
9. VCC --> VIN

When I connect this setup to the computer the arduino uno starts and also the pro mini (both has LED lights on). I upload a simple test code that worked when i tried it with the uno but the BLE device does not respond (it seems like it does not turn on) when i use it with the pro mini.

Any idea what might be wrong? I have my board put as: Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, ATmega328 (5V, 16 MHz).

Thanks a ton!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my wiring: First I connect the pro mini to the uno in order to upload the code looking like this:

```
Arduino Mini Pro to Arduino Uno

RX --> TX
TX --> RX
VCC --> 5v
GND --> GND
RST --> RST
```

How would this work? The bootloader in the Uno and Mini Pro will both try to reply. You need a FTDI or a USB-to-UART module instead of the Uno. Alternatively, start by programming the Uno to act as a USB-to-UART converter using Serial and SoftwareSerial.

Cheers!

Comment: I saw the connection from this thread: http://www.instructables.com/id/SpeechVoice-Controlled-Arduino-Drone/?ALLSTEPS Check under "Step 1". I also found this thread that has similiar connection: http://www.instructables.com/id/Uploading-sketch-to-Arduino-Pro-Mini-using-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: But maybe it will not work to use the Uno as a "code-uploader". I have this at home also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59VHCXNxSvQ Check minute 1.56. I have the red one. Would that work with the Pro mini?

Comment: The second link is fine. The MCU on the Arduino Uno is removed and the board is used as a USB-to-UART. The first link is an SMD AVR MCU and the trick might be the 3.3V setting. The Mini Pro is using 5V.

Comment: Ah ok. I do not have a big MCU/Atmel on my current arduino (i got a chinese copy) and i assume it will be hard to remove it. Did you see the youtube-video, do you think that could work with the pro mini to upload code? It has GND, RXD, TXD and VDD pins

Comment: Use a simple software serial read/write though sketch on the Uno as I suggested. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample

Comment: Yeah could do that but I would prefer to use the USB if it works. When I connect it to my pro mini both light up when i insert the usb to the computer.  Seem to have a little bit of a problem to upload code though

Comment: Looking at the schematics for the Uno it might be possible to force the MCU to disconnect by putting RST to GND. The issue is then to get the signal from the USB MCU to the Mini Pro. Alternatively a manual RST signal for the Mini Pro before upload. This depends on your Chinese copy. Would need the schematics or picture of the board to determine that.

Comment: Picture: http://imgur.com/a/cQj1w where you can see my Uno, Mini pro, FTDI module and also another FTDI module CALLED Crius. it says 3.3V and 5V on the back of it with the pins: GND, CTS, VCC, TXO, RXI, DTR

Comment: Use the blue FTDI module marked FTDI TOOL. It is made to plug into the Mini Pro directly! Check the pin marking. Why use the Uno? You have perfect tools for the job!

Comment: I actually just find it hidden in my box when I went to get a few more cables! Terrific :) Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: When it comes to board-settings, should I still use Arduino Pro Mini?

Comment: Yes, the Arduino IDE setting should be the target board. In this case the Pro Mini. Check frequency (8 or 16 MHz) and voltage (3.3V or 5V).

Comment: Actually you connect the Bluetooth module and connect it so that you can upload over Bluetooth. Google will help you find info about that :)

Comment: The ftdi tool indeed works very well! I just spent 2 hours finding the correct driver for it but finally got it working

Comment: Nice! Here are three links if you want to upload over the Bluetooth module; https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/YoussefSabaa/arduino-bluetooth-programming-shield-wireless-upload-code-1a397c,  https://sites.google.com/site/wayneholder/inexpensively-program-your-arduino-via-bluetooth and simplest https://www.itead.cc/blog/upload-program-to-arduino-with-bt-shield